# Website only works on Internet Explorer Enterprise Mode

Tags: google-chrome, testing, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I was wondering if someone could please give me some advice on how I could make my older website compatible to run on the most popular modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox)? It currently works fine on IEEM but nothing else. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If the site uses special controls(eg  `ActiveX`), I'm afraid it won't work with modern browsers. And we are not sure about the specific situation of the `older website` you mentioned, in this case, I recommend you can use Edge IE mode.

For more details, please refer to this doc：[What is Edge IE mode?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode).

Comment: Thanks @Xudong Peng. That is probably the most effective way to resolve this issue. I just ideally would like the site to operate in other browsers. Especially Chrome and Firefox. Cheers